# Angularjs Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

I am developing shoping website with java and I am using angurajs.

I have problem with thise files:

DashboardControll.js

```
    'use strict';
var app = angular.module("DashboardApp", []);

app.controller("DashboardCtrl", function($scope, $http, Authentication) {
    $http.get("/SalonNamestaja/namestaj")
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.namestaji = response;
    });


        $http.get("/SalonNamestaja/ActiveUser")
        .success(function(response) {
            //console.log(response);


            $(".navbar-brand").empty();
            $(".navbar-brand").append("Dobrodosli " + response.name);

            $scope.activeUser = response;
        });

        console.log(Authentication.getUser());
});

app.run(function(Authentication) {
    Authentication.requestUser();
});
```

Authentication.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('authApp').service('Authentication', function Authentication($q, $http) {
    var authenticatedUser = null;

    return {
        requestUser: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get("/SalonNamestaja/ActiveUser")
            .success(function(user) {
                console.log(user);
                authenticatedUser = user;

                deferred.resolve(user);
            }).error(function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        },

        getUser: function() {
            return authenticatedUser;
        },

        exists: function() {
            return authenticatedUser != null;
        }
    }
})
```

When I load page in browser I get the error :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthenticationProvider%20%3C-%20Authentication

Please can somebody help me to solve this error.

Comment: You need to add ` authApp` as dependency to your module ` DashboardApp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using two `angular.module` inside you application `authApp` & `DashboardApp`, then you should have make available your service to `DashboardApp` module by inject `authApp` into it.

```
var app = angular.module("DashboardApp", ["authApp"]);
```

Assuming `authApp` should be intialize somewhere like this `angular.module('authApp',[])`

Comment: This soled the previous error, but now I get new error
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/modulerr?p0=DashboardApp&p1=Er…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.17%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A203)`

Comment: @MišelAdemi are you initializing `angular.module('authApp',[])` anywhere?

Comment: I changed this line `angular.module('authApp').service('Authentication', function Authentication($q, $http)` in  this `angular.module('authApp', []).service('Authentication', function Authentication($q, $http)`

Comment: @MišelAdemi this file should be loaded first before `DashboardControll.js`

Comment: @MišelAdemi but other way you could use `angular.module('DashboardApp').service`   instead of `angular.module('authApp').service`