# Can't find why [$injector:unpr] occurs in my application, while trying to use base64

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the error below but not sure why.

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: base64Provider <- base64 <- Search
```

I have base64 included in my index.html in the body below the other html

`<script src="bower_components/angular-base64/angular-base64.js"></script>`

And it is installed in my bower under dependencies: `"angular-base64": "^2.0.5",`

Also it is in the dependencies for my module.

I am not sure what is wrong here or what exactly it is complaining about because this part of the app worked when it was in its original code, I am moving over this part to another app.

This is what I have it initialized as:

`angular.module('MyApp', [
    ...,
    'base64'
])`

Comment: You probably did not register it (base64 module) with your angular app/module. Due to lack of information I am going to vote to close the question (we are guessing at this point).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs Uncaught Error: \[$injector:unpr\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098656/angularjs-uncaught-error-injectorunpr)

Comment: do you mean adding it as a dependency? or something else. If something else could you please let me know. Thanks @Igor

Comment: You will have to show some more code, specially your module registration (where you provide the dependencies) and the point of failure (if its in something other than the module like in a controller or service) and its dependencies.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is the point of failure, the traces only point to angular code. I actually even tried to remove the 'base64' dependency that was injected and I still get the same error.

Comment: It happens when you didn't inject the service in your controller, directive or service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's wrong in your code, but if you simply want a base64 encoder/decoder, I'd suggest using this simple script: 
https://gist.github.com/jrmatos/f5d9cbaea5c9ff81141a8956e61e754d

So you can work this way:

```
var stringEncoded = Base64.encode("my string");

console.log(stringEncoded); // bXkgc3RyaW5n

var stringDecoded =  Base64.decode(stringEncoded);

console.log(stringDecoded); // my string
```

Comment: I only need the decoder because this is an existing project that relies on it and I am trying to move part of it to another application. Thanks though it does seem useful if I ever need it.